# JQuery game - Make player move smooth in % values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have this really annoying project were we need to make a game in JQuery. I'm having some problems making my character move the way I want him to. I manage to make the character move but he does not move in %. He adds his own width to the "left:" of him and then animates to that position. This is not good, because when you resize the window they do not "scale with it". Basically, can anyone help me make the player move smoothly in % values! Here is my code! (Variables and comments are in Swedish...)

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Leqca77h/1/

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>JQuery spel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stil.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/start.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/spelareRörelse.js"></script>

</head>
<body onresize="sättSpelareHöjd()">

    <header><h1>Jquery spel</h1></header>
    <br>

    <div id="bana"></div>

</body>
```

stil.css:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

#bana {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: auto;
width: 99%;
height: 70vh;
}

#spelare1 {
background-color: green;
width: 2.7%;
height: 0;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

start.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//var tid = parseInt(prompt("Hur långt ska du spela? (Ange i sekunder)"));

$("#bana").append("<div id='spelare1'></div>");
$("#bana").append("<div id='spelare2'></div>");

sättSpelareHöjd();
});

var knappTryckt1 = true;

function sättSpelareHöjd() {
var spelareHöjd = $("#spelare1").width();
$("#spelare1").css("height", spelareHöjd);
}
```

spelareRörelse.js (playerMovment.js):

```
//Spelare 1 rörelse
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(knappTryckt1) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({left: "-=" + $(this).width()},5000);
        //Pil vänster
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({top: "-=" + $(this).height()},5000);
        //Pil upp
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({left: "+=" + $(this).width()},5000);
        //Pil höger
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        $("#spelare1").stop().animate({top: "+=" + $(this).height()},5000);
        //Pil ner
    }

    knappTryckt1 = false;
    }
 });
 $(document).keyup(function(){
    $("#spelare1").stop();
    knappTryckt1 = true;
 });
```

If you can help! Thanks! :)
JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Leqca77h/1/

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw
Yes! Here is my JSdiffle!
https://jsfiddle.net/Leqca77h/1/

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw No. The players are not moving in % values. If you would resize the window they would have a fixed left: value. I want the value to be in %. So if you press the left key it will go 1% left and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found! Changing:

"left: "-=" + $(this).width()"

to:

"left: "-=" + 100 + "%""

worked for me!